# ruuning tomcat on port 80 using mod_proxy_ajp ( errors)

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, ajp

ive the  tomcat running on  8080

apache running on 80

i implemented

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8080/ retry=0 timeout=30
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8080/
       </Location>
```

i cant access my java app through apache and i keep getting error

```
[Thu May 23 15:47:33 2013] [error] (120006)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: read response failed from (null) (localhost)
[Thu May 23 15:48:15 2013] [error] (70014)End of file found: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header
[Thu May 23 15:48:15 2013] [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
[Thu May 23 15:48:15 2013] [error] (120006)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: read response failed from (null) (localhost)
```

any advise to work around ajp proxy error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check `server.xml` the AJP connector listens by default on port 8009 - you are trying to bind AJP to HTTP connector on port 8080.

Please see [`mod_proxy_ajp` usage information](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html#usage)